# How to login user from inside Facebook Page Tab and get access_token on server side to post a carousel to the feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Page Tab facebook app. I want to post to users timeline from it.

After login on client side with javascript sdk (I use angularjs module for that Ciul/angular-facebook (sorry, cannot post github link here)):

https://gist.github.com/Sevavietl/7e363fdfd0e714a12a43

I retrieve access_token on server side and trying to post a carousel to the users feed:

https://gist.github.com/Sevavietl/cec5fa434837312adfd3

I have two problems:

1. While first call I get
   Graph returned an error: (#210) Param id must be a page.

After browsing, I found that this can be caused by wrong token usage. Not user_access_token. But I login the user on the client side.

2. And for next calls I get
   Graph returned an error: This authorization code has been used.

Again, after browsing, I found that token can be used only once in order to be OAuth compliant.

Please, advise me how to do this right?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Vsevolod

Comment: _“I found that token can be used only once in order to be OAuth compliant”_ – you are confusing _token_ and _code_. The _code_ is what you need to exchange for a token, and _that_ you can do only once.

Comment: You are completely right. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on this, I am writing my solution, as it was not really obvious, at least for me. But, actually, **all info is present in the documentation.**

**Starting with problem number 2: *And for next calls I get Graph returned an error: This authorization code has been used.***

As it was mentioned in the comments, I indeed was confusing access_token with authorization code. As I understand in really simplified form, the mechanism is:

1. When you login with *facebook-javascript-sdk* it writes `authorization code` to cookies.
2. Then on the server side you can retrieve `access_token` from javaScriptHelper available in *facebook-php-sdk*. This helper has `getAccessToken()` method, which retrieves `access_token` using  `authorization code` from cookies. This is the place where I was confused. I was trying to use `getAccessToken()` on every request. As requests were made with AJAX the `authorization code` was not changed, and as you can use it only once I was getting an error. **The solution to this was pointed in many places on the Internet, but somehow I was able to misunderstand this.**
   Here is the code excerpt that uses sessions to store `access_token`, and uses `getAccessToken()` method only if `access_token` is not set in the session.

   ```
       $fb = new Facebook([
           'app_id' => $widget->app_id,
           'app_secret' => $widget->app_secret,
           'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
       ]);

       $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();

       if ($request->session()->has('facebook_access_token')) {
           $accessToken = $request->session()->get('facebook_access_token');
       } else {
           $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

           // OAuth 2.0 client handler
           $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

           // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
           $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
           $request->session()->put('facebook_access_token', (string) $longLivedAccessToken);
           $request->session()->save();
       }

       if ($accessToken) {
           $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
       } else {
           die('No Access Token');
       }
   ```

I use Laravel, so the session handling is not framework agnostic. This code is only for example, it is better to create service and move logic there.

**Now. About the first problem: While first call I get Graph returned an error: *(#210) Param id must be a page*.**

Again I was confusing two things [`'{user-id}/feed'`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed) and [`'{page-id}/feed'`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed).  My aim was to post a *carousel with images and links*. To create a carousel you have to provide `child_attachments` in the fields array. While you can send a Post like this to `'{page-id}/feed'`, you cannot do so for `'{user-id}/feed'`. **So at the moment you cannot post a carousel to users feed.**
So when Graph Api was getting a Post data applicable for `'{page-id}/feed'`, it was assuming that I have passed the `{page-id}`. And when getting the `{user-id}` instead, the Graph Api yelled back *"(#210) Param id must be a page."*.